# PHP Twitter Search API - ForEach() Not Working

Tags: php, json, twitter

This is a stupid easy question for some of you, but i can't seem to get a result printed out.

I keep getting Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\td.php on line 14

Thanks

```
$url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=shoes&include_entities=true&rpp=2";

$data = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($result->results as $data) {
    echo $data->created_at;
}
```

The json return looks like this.

```
Array
(
    [completed_in] => 0.019
    [max_id] => 1.4886632421341E+17
    [max_id_str] => 148866324213411841
    [next_page] => ?page=2&max_id=148866324213411841&q=shoes&rpp=2&include_entities=1
    [page] => 1
    [query] => shoes
    [refresh_url] => ?since_id=148866324213411841&q=shoes&include_entities=1
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [created_at] => Mon, 19 Dec 2011 20:44:32 +0000
    ...
    etc
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$result` is an array but you're treating it like an object. Likewise, its inner component `$results` is also an array of associative arrays, but you've treated it as an object.  `$data` in context of your loop is an array having `created_at` as one of its keys:

```
// Access [results] as an array key
foreach ($result['results'] as $data) {
    // $data is $results[0], $results[1], ...,$results[n]
    // [created_at] is an array key of $results[n]
    echo $data['created_at'];
}
```

Comment: Yup that was that.  I tried $result['results'] but didnt' also change to $data['created_at'].  Thanks!